# How to get value from ping result?

Tags: python

What regular expression must I do in python in `re.findall()` to get value of percent loss packet?
The problem is that the result written to the variable has the form one time:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
300 packets transmitted, 300 received, 0% packet loss, time 299466ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.976/4.225/26.866/3.043 ms
```

and the other time:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
300 packets transmitted, 299 received, 0,333333% packet loss, time 299452ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.231/4.878/19.140/2.807 ms
```

What the regular expression should look like in code?

```
wynik_ip_modem = os.popen("ping -c 5 -q 192.168.1.1").read()
wynik_procent = re.findall('???????',wynik_ip_modem)
```

to read the value of lost packets alone, whether if the ping result is a decimal or an integer?

Comment: Was the comma in the second example a mistake? I don't think there's supposed to be a comma there, only a `.`

Comment: no in my result in ping on the linux is comma this is not mistake

Comment: Ok... I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(\d*[\.|\,]?\d+)%`
The breakdown can be seen here: https://regex101.com/r/amVdfY/3

The reason this works is `%` is only found in the packet loss part.

Comment: what is the easiest way to remove the % from result in python, i have to convert it to a string and use the strip function is there an easier way?

Comment: Updated the answer :D